# Errors in system.log

Tags: magento-1.9

Can anyone assist with these errors showing in our **system.log**?

```
2017-09-25T19:14:27+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 133

2017-09-25T19:14:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal offset type  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 177

2017-09-25T19:22:22+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 133

2017-09-25T19:22:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal offset type  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 177
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you have a bad layout XML node value in an extending theme. Start by searching your layout XML for a culprit, possibly via grep; ex:

```
grep -rn 'method="addItem"' app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/layout -A1
```

And look for possible causes. Judging by the error message, my guess is that you have an invalid structure that *could* look like this:

```
...
<action method="addItem">
    <type>
        <extraneous_node>skin_js</extraneous_node>
    </type>
    <value>js/file.js</value>
</action>
...
```

Where `extraneous_node` would cause that XML fragment to be treated as an array when processed by the layout system. In the case of the `addItem` method, your XML should only specify 2 child nodes, *like* `type` and `value`, each with a direct node value (no children).

**Update**: Alternative Option

You could also try to edit the core block directly to catch the culprit, like this:

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php
...
public function addItem($type, $name, $params=null, $if=null, $cond=null)
{
    if ($type==='skin_css' && empty($params)) {
        $params = 'media="all"';
    }

    // START: DEBUG
    if (is_array($type) || is_array($name)) {
        Zend_Debug::dump(func_get_args());
        exit;
    }
    // END: DEBUG

    $this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name] = array(
        'type'   => $type,
        'name'   => $name,
        'params' => $params,
        'if'     => $if,
        'cond'   => $cond,
   );
    return $this;
}
...
```

If my guess is right, the debug code will catch the incoming malformed data and output what it has at that moment so you can trace it back to the line of layout XML. This is the same approach I'd take if using a tool like XDebug, like setting a breakpoint in this method to catch every call to it.

Comment: Hi Rick and thanks for the information... Just to note the theme used has been based on the RWD theme so I've run that command and got this result but can't find any offending line... Edit: I can't paste the reslut in here as it's too long, so... https://www.theappliancedepot.co.uk/result.txt

Comment: What folder did you scan over? I'm surprised to see no `local.xml` references in the output. Short of using a profiler like XDebug, you could try to add a check in the block directly. Updating my answer to explain what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I was scanning app/design/frontend/rwd/adepot/layout  I can also confirm the existance of a local.xml file with the content... https://www.theappliancedepot.co.uk/local.xml.txt I will try adding the debug lines as you mention to find the issue. thanks again

Comment: Hi again, ok i tried adding the debug code but it's not outputting the error anywhere, just getting the same errors in system.log?